# @Override and Super

Tags: java, android, super

It seems to me that when you override methods you intend to modify their usefulness.
But why evoke the same method in the superclass (in the way in which it was originally written) if it does not interest me like that? That is, modifying the method and then calling the same method on the original way it seems to me that the first change was undone by the second. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Trevor, most methods that require you calling super() means that the method you're overriding is necessary for a process lifecycle to go smoothly (as in Activities' onCreate, onPause, etc). If you fail to return super on these methods, android will complain.

On the other hand, other overridden methods that call super (you can see them when extending Android classes such as View) actually returns something (most likely a true or false) - as in some `return super.methodName(args);` - depending on the circumstance, you can override these to the point that you can manually return a value and skip on the super call.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily *have* to call `.super()` in order to invoke the method in the superclass from which your class is derived. However, very often you do so, because the stuff you're doing in your overridden method should be done *in addition* to the stuff performed by the superclass's method. Whether or not you do it depends on the design of the code concerned.

Some Android API methods absolutely require you to call `.super()` when you override them, because there's some important stuff that the superclass's method absolutely most do, even if a derived class overrides that method. If you must call `.super()` when overriding an Android API method, the documentation usually states so. If you fail to do so you may get an exception specifically telling you off for not doing so when you execute the code.

Comment: I was just wondering, how can the corresponding class check that super was callend - and if it wasn't throw an exception?

Comment: I guess one way to do it could be as simple as implementing a flag `boolean` that is set in the superclass's method (which a derived class could override) and poll that flag in another method, and throw an exception if not set. For example, this way you'd detect if `doSomeStuff()` was called without a call to the base class `initialiseStuffFirst()` happening prior.

Comment: The android `Activity` class has examples of methods where you must call `.super()` if you override them - might be worth looking at the source code on Grepcode to see how they detect it.

Comment: Thanks to all you guys. I understood the explanation of Trevor Page. Very good. If I understood correctly, is very curious that an overridden method remains the same in their functionality in the superclass.